# factor analysis on multiple imputation using SPSS

Tags: factor-analysis, missing-data, multiple-imputation

There seems to be many questions on MI but I still can't find the answer for FA in SPSS, so here it is:

I have 2.6% missing data on a small sample for a likert scale question.  After running a multiple imputation and obtaining 5 iterations, I split the data and ran a factor analysis on each of the 5 MI iterations.  Now I am not sure how to pool the results of the 5 completed FAs.

Some forums have suggested finding the mean and then using some formula (which I do not know) to find the degrees of freedom.

I am looking for the easiest method since my statistic abilities are very limited.  I have already tried expectation maximization but i receive negative integers which makes the results impossible as i need a response between 1 to 5 (or 0 to 4).

Thanks